# ListView sum column total and display in label returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, itemdatabound

I'm trying to sum all the values from the July column into a label with ID of july. Here's the markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="leaveListView" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" OnItemDataBound="leaveListView_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="budgetList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Project Number</td>
                    <td>Account</td>
                    <td>Project Name</td>
                    <td>July</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="projectRowTotal">
                    <td>Project Totals</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="july" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "even" %>">
            <td><%# Eval("Project") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Account") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("ProjectNumber") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("July") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I'm using the ItemDataBound event to sum, but it's returning null. This is the code-behind:

```
decimal july = 0m;
protected void leaveListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
            july += Convert.ToDecimal(e.Item.FindControl("July"));            
    }
    Label julySum = (Label)leaveListView.FindControl("july");
    julySum.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", (decimal?)july);
}
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: why not use linq Sum method and just bind to that ?

Comment: It's in the `Layout`- not the `ItemTemlate`, so don't you need `leaveListView.FindControl` instead of `e.Item.FindControl`? In your `ItemTemplate` is no control at all with an ID.

Comment: So do I use the LayoutCreated event?

Comment: you can actually do it this way too : <table><thead /><ListView /><tfoot /></table> , now you have a direct access to Label from the code. But as suggested, you create the rows based on some data, why dont you make a sum in code and just simply put july.Text = <value> ... too (in code where you bind data )?

Comment: in addition then you could remove leaveListView_ItemDataBound completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as my comments suggested, here is solution:

```
<table class="budgetList">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <td>Project Number</td>
           <td>Account</td>
           <td>Project Name</td>
           <td>July</td>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <asp:ListView ID="leaveListView" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder">
       <LayoutTemplate>
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
       </LayoutTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "even" %>">
           <td><%# Eval("Project") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("Account") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("ProjectNumber") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("July") %></td>
        </tr>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
   </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr class="projectRowTotal">
                <td>Project Totals</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="july" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

havent't actually tried it, but should work fine ... + in code, where you bind data:

```
 leaveListView.ItemsSource = <data>;
 // simply place the value in label directly
 july.Text = <data.sum>
```

now just make sum in code and you're done, no need for itemdatabound event

Answer (score 0):

`e.Item.FindControl("July")` return null because no control with that existing in the `ListView`

### Solution

You want to store `July`'s value into HiddenField (or some other field) so that you can retrieve them back in ItemDataBound event.

```
<asp:ListView ID="leaveListView"...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "even" %>">
            <td><%# Eval("Project") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Account") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("ProjectNumber") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("July") %></td>
        </tr>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="JulyHiddenField" 
           Value="<%# Eval("July") %>"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

decimal july = 0m;
protected void leaveListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, 
  ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var hiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("JulyHiddenField") as HiddenField;
        july += Convert.ToDecimal(hiddenField.Value);            
    }
    Label julySum = (Label)leaveListView.FindControl("july");
    julySum.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", (decimal?)july);
}
```

### For Good Design Practice

Please name your control properly. Eg. `<asp:Label ID="JulyLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>`. Currently, you have no way of knowing is `july` is what.